# Gitlab runner and keychain

Tags: ssh, gitlab, keychain

Recently I have configured a Gitlab Runner on a VM and I wanted to add keychain on that VM to allow runner to execute commands like scp or SSH without exposing my SSH passphras (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/)

And when I install gitlab-multi-runner (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html) I see a new folder "`gitlab-runner`" in my `/home`.

So I added a password to this user (passwd command), edit its .bash_profile as described in the link above, and generate new SSH keys.

My runner is working fine, my .gitlab-ci.yml can execute scp commands like this :

```
scp jon.doe YOUR_LOGIN@DEV_SERVER_ADDRESS:/var/www/
```

No passphrase required / exposed.

So here my questions:

1. Is it safe to configure runner like this ?
2. Is there an official or better way, to do what i want ? (use SSH and SCP safely with a gitlab-runner)

I think there should be no problem, but I'm not an expert in Linux and SSH so...

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to configure runner like this ?

If only you are running the jobs it is ok.

If somebody else (you don't trust) can push any arbitrary command into your `.gitlab-cy.yml`, he can basically run any arbitrary code on your virtual machine and on your other machine (which is certainly not what you want).

You should restrict your remote user `YOUR_LOGIN` on your dev server to do the minimum needed by `ForceCommand` (`scponly` or just the forced command to `scp` into specific directory), block port forwarding and possibly use chroot.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what i wanted. But I believe I only can use `ForceCommand` with `internal-sftp` and not `scp`.
But chroot and block port forwarding is what I should do =)
More info : https://passingcuriosity.com/2014/openssh-restrict-to-sftp-chroot/

Comment: With `sftp`, it would be easier (with better performance). For scp, there is utility [`scponly`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/scponly) to set as user shell.